# Compare or filter values from two Json arrays in typescript

Tags: arrays, json, typescript

I am facing the problem of comparing arrays and filtering the data rows.
I want to filter the data from array1 which is not included in array2 list. 
But, I think My logic was wrong with nested array. Could you please help me?

Here is my sample code:

```
let array1=[{"cblSchKey":693698,"projCode":"11-1115","cblTagNo":"571_GE001-E"},{"cblSchKey":734106,"projCode":"11-1115","cblTagNo":"4000-JB01/4054M1"},{"cblSchKey":725484,"projCode":"11-1115", "cblTagNo": "571_GE001- RC1"},{"cblSchKey":693700,"projCode":"11-1115", "cblTagNo": "571_GE001-S"}];
let array2=[{ "projCode": "11-1115","pullDate": "2019-09-15", "cablePullDtl": [{"cblSchKey": 693698, "remarks": null,"remarks2": "test"}]
},{"projCode": "11-1115","pullDate": "2019-10-01","cablePullDtl":[{"cblSchKey":734106, "remarks": null,"remarks2": "",}]}];
let array3=[]; let array4=[];
for (var j=0; j<array1.length; j++){
     for(var k=0; k<array2.length; k++){
          let PullDtl =[];
              PullDtl = array2[k].cablePullDtl; 
       for(var i=0; i<PullDtl .length; i++){
          if(array1[j].cblSchKey == PullDtl [i].cblSchKey){ 
               array3.push(array1[j]);
           }else {
               array4.push(array1[j]);      
        }
     }  
   }  
 }
 console.log("InValid"+JSON.stringify(array3));
 console.log("Valid"+JSON.stringify(array4));
```

I want to get 2 arrays as below after filtered.

```
array3=[{"cblSchKey":693698,"projCode":"11-1115","cblTagNo":"571_GE001-E"},{"cblSchKey":734106,"projCode":"11-1115","cblTagNo":"4000-JB01/4054M1"}];
array4=[{"cblSchKey":725484,"projCode":"11-1115", "cblTagNo": "571_GE001- RC1"},"cblSchKey":693700,"projCode":"11-1115", "cblTagNo": "571_GE001-S"}];
```

Comment: you can use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/linq , pretty easy to use

Comment: @EJL I will try to explore how to use it for filtering json arrays. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let array3 = [];
let array4 = [];
array1.forEach(i => {
  let a = array2.find(i2 => i2.cablePullDtl.find(c => c.cblSchKey === i.cblSchKey));
  if (a === undefined) {
    array4.push(i);
  } else {
    array3.push(i);
  }
});
```

Comment: Omg! You saved my life a lot. Thank you so much.  _/\_